# Service Bus TopicClient thread safety and client side batching

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have gone through the best practices for Service Bus mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements

Looks like it discusses about the old Service Bus library. I am using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.TopicClient and have couple of queries:

1. Is it thread safe?
2. How do I enable client-side batching for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it thread safe?

Yes.

> How do I enable client-side batching for this?

You don't. That setting was specific to SBMP protocol. The new client is using AMQP only.